# asp.net core 1 rc2: Creating a view component

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I completely migrated a aspnet 5 rc1 project into the aspnet core-rc2 and made sure everything is working the same as before; however, I can't seem to get my ViewComponents to work in rc2 and I'm not exactly sure how to implement it in the "new" way.

Here is how I have it set up right now:

Somewhere in the a .cshtml file i have:

```
 @Component.Invoke("AddActivity", Model.Id)
```

then I have the viewcomponent in a folder

```
public class AddActivityViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int id)
    {
        ActivityViewModel model = new ActivityViewModel();
        model.IssueId = id;

        return View("ActivityModal", model);
    }
}
```

and with this it would normally return the ActivityModal cshtml in the shared folder however RC2 seems to be asking for a class that implements IViewComponentHelper?

Please let me know if I'm doing something incorrectly or if there's a better way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: The Sync APIs have been removed in rc2.

Your code may be like that:

```
public class AddActivityViewComponent : ViewComponent

{

    public IViewComponentResult InvokeAsync(int id)
    {
        ActivityViewModel model = new ActivityViewModel();
        model.IssueId = id;

        return View("ActivityModal", model);
    }
}

@Component.InvokeAsync<AddActivityViewComponent>(new { id = Model.Id})
```

or

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync<AddActivityViewComponent>(new { id = Model.Id})
```

Comment: Thank you ! Your suggestion with the above code + the @await Component.InvokeAsync(new { id = Model.Id}) worked perfectly.

Comment: This still did not work for me. I had to change the method signature like this "public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int id)" ...... and had to call it with await otherwise it would return a weird string instead of the view

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they changed how Components are invoked in RC2. Now the Invoke method only takes one argument with "key/value pairs" as parameters.
So maybe something like this would work:

```
@Component.Invoke("AddActivity", new { id = Model.Id})
```

More info [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3973).

Comment: I saw this, but I'm even able to call a simple ViewComponent with no parameters in RC2. Don't know whats going on. I'll try to dig into.

Answer (score 0):

What Isaac and Andrey said is corretct. I would just like to add: 
the name of the parameters need to match.

In your case, you need to call invoke with `new { id = Model.Id}` as your parameter in the invoke method is called "id".